# Value pack expansion can only appear inside a function argument list or tuple element compile error when moving to Swift 5.10

Tags: swift, swift-data

Consider the following code which just sets a predicate on init in a view which used to work fine with Swift 5.9

```swift
let predicate: Predicate<Transaction> = if let accountName {
    #Predicate<Transaction> { transaction in
        transaction.account?.name == accountName
    }
} else {
    #Predicate<Transaction> { _ in
        true
    }
}
```

This causes the following compile error in 5.10

> Value pack expansion can only appear inside a function argument list or tuple element

I tried figuring out what has changed and came across a few discussions related to this error, but couldn't really figure out why this is now failing.

I had an inkling it had something to do with macro expansion and the `if let` expression. Whether that is correct or not, I did manage to fix my issue like so:

My code now builds and works fine now, but would be interested in understanding what changed in 5.10 to cause this and if maybe there is a more elegant way of handling it.

Note that `swiftformat` appears to automatically re-format this expression to my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution

```
var predicate: Predicate<Transaction> = Predicate.true

if let accountName {
    predicate = #Predicate<Transaction> { transaction in
        transaction.account?.name == accountName
    }
}
```

Comment: Both are much neater than my workaround and they have the advantage of not being modified by `swiftformat`

Comment: @wombat I removed the second one, I was sure it was going to work but I get an error when the variable is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with this error, here is how I solved it

```swift
let predicate: Predicate<Transaction>

if let accountName {
    predicate = #Predicate<Transaction> { transaction in
        transaction.account?.name == accountName
    }
} else {
    predicate = #Predicate<Transaction> { _ in
        true
    }
}
```